Android 14 device not receiving Intent.ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED
I'm trying to relaunch my application after it is reinstalled and updated by downloading it from the landing page. I've created a receiver like the one shown below, the implementation to launch the application is still remaining but I'm not receiving the text present in the log as well:
class UpdateReceiver: BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        Logger.d("upgradeissue","getting log")
        if(intent?.action == Intent.ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED){
            val packageName = intent.data?.schemeSpecificPart
            if(packageName == context?.packageName && packageName != null){
                val launchIntent = context?.packageManager?.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName)
                launchIntent?.let {
                    it.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
                    context.startActivity(it)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

I'm listening for the intent by declaring it in the manifest as shown below:
<receiver
            android:name=".common.UpdateReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <data android:scheme="package"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED"/>
            </intent-filter>
</receiver>

I've went through other answers here but none of them seem to apply to me. I'm updating the application by downloading it from the landing page, not by reinstalling it through android studio.
Haven't tried this on any other android version but the current device is Android 14, and the requirement to relaunch app after updation is present on Android 14 too.

Two issues here, ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED is not part of the exempt broadcasts that you can declare in your manifest.
In Android 14 you cannot start activities from the background except for a few exceptions

From what we can see in this documentation here, the apps won't receive PACKAGE_REPLACED intent but they will still receive MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED as long as the intent is targeted for the specific app.
